# printing on a document c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

i am trying to print a invoice from application for my dads business, i am using the following code to print the invoice.

My attempt is below:

```
{

int y = 470;
        while (i < dataGridView1.RowCount)
        {    
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ProductName"].Value.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(35, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Desc"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(250, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(600, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["UnitPrice"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(650, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Tax"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(700, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(650, y));
            y = y + 20;
            if (y >= pageHeight)
            {

                e.HasMorePages = true;
                y = 0;
                i++;
                return;
           }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

i here is a global variable

`private int i = 0;`

when i click on preview button i get the output as expected but when i print it on paper only the content in the while loop is not printed. i tried using a local variable instead j of global variable as shown below and it worked.

```
for (int j=0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["ProductName"].Value.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(35, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Desc"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(250, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(600, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["UnitPrice"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(650, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Tax"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(700, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(650, y));
            y = y + 20;
        }
```

but i don't know how to add new pages if the item to be included exceeds the page height. please some help.

Comment: So as to avoid essentially a link-only answer, [dreamincode](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c%23/) has a good article on printing multiple pages to a printer. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx) also has a decent example, if you can speak Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

after iterating through the code step by step i found that the code tp print the preview is run again while printing the form. so i just had to initialize the i value to 0 so that it starts printing from the beginning.

here is the code which solved it

```
int j;
        for (j=i; j < dataGridView1.RowCount && y<e.MarginBounds.Bottom; j++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.MarginBounds.Bottom.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(100, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["ProductName"].Value.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(35, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Desc"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(220, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(770, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["UnitPrice"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(620, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Tax"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(670, y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(720, y));
            y = y + 20;
        }
        if (j < dataGridView1.RowCount)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            i=j;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            i = 0;
        }
```